# Развертка двойного цикла

Tags: c, оптимизация

Простой случай оптимизации "развертка цикла" предполагает,что  такой цикл:

```
for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
ret[j] += a[i] * b[j];
```

превратится в такой:

```
for (j = 0; j < d; j+=5)
        {
            ret[j] += a[i] * b[j];
            ret[j+1] += a[i] * b[j+1];
            ret[j+2] += a[i] * b[j+2];
            ret[j + 3] += a[i] * b[j + 3];
            ret[j + 4] += a[i] * b[j + 4];

        }
```

Но как поступить, если цикл изначально такой:

```
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
            ret[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
    }
```

На ум приходит только такая оптимизация

```
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < d; j+=5)
        {
            ret[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
            ret[i + j+1] += a[i] * b[j+1];
            ret[i + j+2] += a[i] * b[j+2];
            ret[i + j + 3] += a[i] * b[j + 3];
            ret[i + j + 4] += a[i] * b[j + 4];

        }
    }
```

Но есть ли возможность включить в оптимизацию ещё и внешний цикл?

Comment: Что значит "включить в оптимизацию"? Любая развёртка предполагает уменьшение кол-ва итераций путём кратного увеличения кода, по сути дублирование.

Comment: @älёxölüt,я имею в виду,задействовать итерации внешнего цикла

Comment: С вероятностью 20% ваша развертка вызовет исключение по доступу к памяти. Чтобы это работало, нужно гарантировать, что `d` кратно 5. И вообще, компилятор с разворачиванием циклов справляется гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 0):

А так?

```
for (i=0;i<d;i+=5){
        ret[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
        ret[i + j+1] += a[i] * b[j+1];
        ret[i + j+2] += a[i] * b[j+2];
        ret[i + j + 3] += a[i] * b[j + 3];
        ret[i + j + 4] += a[i] * b[j + 4];

        ret[i+1 + j] += a[i+1] * b[j];
        ret[i+1 + j+1] += a[i+1] * b[j+1];
        ret[i+1 + j+2] += a[i+1] * b[j+2];
        ret[i+1 + j + 3] += a[i+1] * b[j + 3];
        ret[i+1 + j + 4] += a[i+1] * b[j + 4];

        ret[i+2 + j] += a[i+2] * b[j];
        ret[i+2 + j+1] += a[i+2] * b[j+1];
        ret[i+2 + j+2] += a[i+2] * b[j+2];
        ret[i+2 + j + 3] += a[i+2] * b[j + 3];
        ret[i+2 + j + 4] += a[i+2] * b[j + 4];

        ret[i+3 + j] += a[i+3] * b[j];
        ret[i+3 + j+1] += a[i+3] * b[j+1];
        ret[i+3 + j+2] += a[i+3] * b[j+2];
        ret[i+3 + j + 3] += a[i+3] * b[j + 3];
        ret[i+3 + j + 4] += a[i+3] * b[j + 4];

        ret[i+4 + j] += a[i+4] * b[j];
        ret[i+4 + j+1] += a[i+4] * b[j+1];
        ret[i+4 + j+2] += a[i+4] * b[j+2];
        ret[i+4 + j + 3] += a[i+4] * b[j + 3];
        ret[i+4 + j + 4] += a[i+4] * b[j + 4];
}
```